# upload more images per row in magento static block

Tags: css, magento

please visit this link :

below slideshow images, you can see a static block contains some 6 images with some text.

i can not able to upload more than 4 images per row.

if i resize the image by width ="50" also, it's not taking width value.

but height is updating.

i want to upload unlimited images per row.

please help me to find solution.

thanks in advance.

Comment: If I understand your problem correctly, you have to change the width in `.box_banner li` in theme.css file. Change the width from 24% to 14% and you can put more images there.

Comment: you are right.... you can post this as an answer.... thanks a lot....

Comment: Good to know that it worked for you. Have added it as answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your problem correctly, you have to change the width in **.box_banner li** in `theme.css` file. Change the width from 24% to 14% and you can put more images there.